# Element is already the child of another element - wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, parent-child

***Edited***

I have a paragraph object attached to a richtextbox.
I've created a click event to switch between two paragraphs in the richTextBOx, but I always get this exception even that i'm clearing the richTetxBox.
My code

```
    public bool Collapsed
    {
        set
        {
            _collapsed = value;

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            richTextBox.Blocks.Clear();

            if (_collapsed)
            {
                p = backupParagraph;
                richTextBox.Blocks.Add(p);
            }
            else
            {
                p = paragraph;
                richTextBox.Blocks.Add(p);
            }

        }
        get
        {
            return _collapsed;
        }
    }
```

I have an event which fired when user tap the object

```
     void rtb_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Collapsed = !_collapsed;
    }
```

And trying this I had this in my mainPage

```
            p.Title = "Tryout";
        p.Text = "Hello Hello <small>Hello</small> Hello, <b>is it gonna</b> change? <big>why</big> <small>don't</small>";
        p.Collapsed = true;

        ContentPanel2.Children.Add(p.richTextBox);
```

Now when I tap the object, I get the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that you have added the rich text box or paragraph text in another control. Or just post your codes fully i will help you

Comment: I'm afraid you have to create a copy of either backupParagraph or paragraph before adding them to Blocks property again. As far as I know, this is a known Silverlight bug. reagards,

Comment: Well I tried to do so. I have created an inner type paragraph which initialized every time I call collapsed, and it still giving me that exception.